# How to solve issue of Exhausted heap space in Flutter Project

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

All most every time when I built a flutter project and start working on it, after sometimes when projects start becoming mature this exhausted heap space issue starts troubling me. 
Is anything wrong with the Project Settings or Updates or Gradle Issue, How to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking to the few coders who faced this issue got to know that problem is with RAM and Disc Space.
When Chrome + Android Studio and a few other heavy application which are already craving for more memory and when any editor runs and builds the project then more system resources comes to use which result in lagging down the build speed and might also result in fail build.
[image]

Comment: all the other projects work completely fine with chrome. This issue could be because of latest flutter sdk i.e. 1.17.x